# Edit objects in database using forms and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Okay so I have been trying to figure out how to edit an object in a database using a form, that has the instance of the object I want to update.

I want to be able to edit multiple objects from the same page but each have a form of their own. That's why I want to use ajax to perform the request and update the page without refreshing.

I cant seem to update the template specially the form?

Here is my code.

**View**

```
@login_required
def update(request):
if request.user.id:
    uid = request.user.id
    user_Books = Books.objects.filter(user_upload_id = uid) #Gets the users books
    User = UserProfile.objects.get(pk = uid) 

if request.is_ajax():
    Book = user_Books.get( pk = request.POST.get('id') ) #querys for the specifc book form ajax id value
    form = Book_Submit(instance = Book)

    return render(request, 'Forms/update.html', {'user_Books'user_Books,'form':form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))    

return render(request, 'Forms/update.html', {'user_Books':user_Books, }, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.Book_list').append(function(){
    $('#edit', this).click(function(){
        var a = $(this).parent().find("p").text()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: {"id":a},
            success: function(){           
                $('form').load('update.html')
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            }
       });
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="container">

        {% for bk in user_Books %}
            <div class="Book">
                <h2 id="title">{{ bk.title }}</h2>
                <p>{{ bk.id }}</p>
                <input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit"></input>

                <div id="form">
                    <form>
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, a little more care when reading the documentation would have saved me time. All I did was just send a post requesting the object, then place the object within the form as an instance and return render the form to the page.

You can use ajax to $.post and take the data returned from the post.

```
Book = user_Books.objects.get(pk=i)
updateform = Form(instance=Book)

return render(request,'Forms/update.html',{
  'updateform':updateform,
        },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```